# Nested PHP ternary operator precedence

Tags: php, conditional-operator

Yes, I know this is very bad code, but I'd still like to understand it:

```
$out = $a > 9 && $a < 15 ? "option1" : $a < 5 ? "option2" : "option3";

$out = $a > 9 && $a < 15 ? "option1" : ($a < 5 ? "option2" : "option3");
```

If `$a` is 11, then the result of the 1st line is "option 2", but in the 2nd line, the result is "option 1" - what effect is the pair of brackets having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first line is parsed like so:

```
$out = ($a > 9 && $a < 15 ? "option1" : $a < 5) ? "option2" : "option3";
```

Which is equivalent to the following (when `$a == 11`):

```
$out = "option1" ? "option2" : "option3";
```

`"option1"` coerced to boolean is `true`, so the above evaluates to `"option2"`.

The second is being parsed as you would expect:

```
$out = ($a > 9 && $a < 15) ? "option1" : ($a < 5 ? "option2" : "option3");
```

Comment: Ah, thanks! Is there a reason PHP internally puts brackets in the middle of the ternary statement instead of just reading from left to right?

Comment: No... that's not quite it. The actual parse is even sillier. Hang on.

Comment: @ChrisW My original answer was actually wrong. I've fixed it. It is parsed like that, because of the left associativity of the ternary operator.

Answer (score 7):

The unparenthesized code you've got is parsed as:

```
$out = (
    (
        ($a < 9 && $a < 15)
        ? ("option1")
        : ($a < 5) 
    )
    ? ( "option2" )
    : ( "option3" )
);
```

This is because [PHP's ternary operator is left-associative](http://www.phpsadness.com/sad/30). This is the exact opposite of the way it works in *every other language*, and ends up interpreting chained ternary expressions in a surprising (and almost always useless!) way. This is widely regarded as a bug, but one that's "too old to fix", much like some similar precedence issues with C's binary operators.

Adding the parentheses in your second expression yields the intended:

```
$out = (
    ($a > 9 && $a < 15)
    ? ("option1")
    : (
        ($a < 5)
        ? ("option2")
        : ("option3")
    )
);
```